# Rename uploaded image in multer using fs

Tags: regex, node.js, express, fs, multer

When a user uploads a picture - I'm using multer by the way - with a name that contains a space, I want to replace the white-spaces with `"-"` before saving the file name to my Mysql table and then also rename the file that has been uploaded to the new name with the `"-"`.
This is my code. It does rename and the Mysql table saves the new name with the hyphen but the image doesn't get uploaded for some reason, there's no error even, infact the POST request is actually successful.

```
router.post('/uploadpost', upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
var name = req.file.originalname;
var reName;
if(/\s/g.test(name)){
    reName = name.replace(" ", "-");
    fs.rename(req.file.path, reName, function(err){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to use the original name? I would be concerned about malicious paths....

Comment: @mscdex What do you suggest I do? rename every uploaded image to an arbitrary string?

Comment: Well, currently by default disk storage saves to disk using a random/unique filename consisting of 16 hex digits. The filename (not the absolute path) is available on the `req.file.filename` property. So you could just move that to whatever location you want/need. For example: `fs.rename(req.file.path, path.join('/my/upload/storage', req.file.filename), ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the name when you save the file by Multer?
Something like that:

```
function generateName(){
   return 'newname';
}

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, generateName()); // generate new name 
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Documentation - https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage

Answer (score 1):

You can Change file names easily in `multer` like hown below

```
const multer = require('multer');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        let path = `tmp/upload`;
        fs.mkdirsSync(path);
        cb(null, path);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

in above code I am giving file name like this `file.fieldname` fieldname is name of field using which you are sending images like fieldname could be `"image"` or anything and than - , `Date.now()` the date when you are uploading image and in last type or `extension` of file
ex  `images-1602486722326.jpeg`

***OR***

you can keep original name of image if you want like below

```
 filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
```

this will get originalame of file and give it to the file which you are uploading
**UPDATE**
AND in MemoryStorage

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'bucket_name',
        acl: 'public-read',
        key: function (request, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);    |--------------  change name here which you want to use
                                  |              
            cb(null, file.originalname);  use
        }
    })
}).array('upload', 1);
```

Comment: Hi, what if i am using memoryStorage instead of diskStorage, how do i rename my originalname before storing it in memory?

Comment: het @kd12345 i have updated my answer please check it out

Comment: Hi, did you manage to have a look at my question?